# moving website to localhost to an actual host

Tags: php, sql, xampp, localhost

I created a website on my xampp server that has its own SQL server etc, and I decided to move it to an online actual host with its own mySQL DB based on its own control panel, can anyone tell me the list of changes I need to make in the PHP code of the website (like the DB name, and the hostname in the mysqli command etc) in order to do it.

I mean what changes do I make in the statement

```
new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
```

this is the clearest i can get it to be.

Comment: MySQL and MongoDB are _completely_ different things. You can't write code for the former, point it at the latter, and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using OOP programming making your project, then you have to change connection parameters in your conf.php (exactly - ("localhost", "root", "", "dbname")). Only localhost will be replace with server IP address, server username, password and db name.
And the whole DB must be exported from xampp and imported in MongoDB. But be careful with the data types. As they are different databases, data types could be different as well. 
The best way is to export DB structure in sql file, then change data types in sql file according to MongoDB and then import into server db - MariaDB. And then export all the data from mysql and import it into MariaDB. With data you should't have such problems.